# I need to increment a number every second using threads in android

Tags: android, java-threads, android-threading

Here I am doing it using Handler but it only increments a number once. I want it to increment the number until I stop it using handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);.

Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve this. I am just new to android.

```
   Handler handler;
handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        count++;

                    }
                }, 1000);
```

Comment: If you exit the app, do you want to still run the process?

Comment: no i don't need it at exit app

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277367/android-studio-add-number-every-second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a Thread a start it.

```
   Thread counterThread=new Thread(()->{
            try{
                while(true){
                counter++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
        });
    counterThread.start();
```

And when you want to stop this thread call **counterThread.interrupt();**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Handler handler;
handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         count++;
         handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

- rerun the runnable every second
- use AlarmManager.

I'd suggest you to check out [this link](https://wangjingke.com/2016/09/23/Multiple-ways-to-schedule-repeated-tasks-in-android) to get deeper understanding on multiple ways how to implement the post delayed or alarm manager to repeat a task every X seconds.

EDIT: I'd suggest you to stop the handler in onPause method.